# Java doesn't print each element in txt-file

Tags: java, printwriter

I have a little understanding question, because the code

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\...\\Test.txt");
for(int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++)
{
    out.println(i);
}
```

should write all digits to 100000 in a txt-file, but it stops at 98720.

The question is why is Java doing this?

Comment: What do you mean, it "stops"? Does the JVM crash, or hang?

Comment: The termination of the program was successful but the last few digits weren't in the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might need to flush and close the print writer when you're done with it.

```
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add some extra code at the end.

```
// flush the contents of the stream
out.flush();
// close the stream, and release its resources
out.close();
```